# Python: How can I store a variable changed by the user?

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I am writing a program where basically you type information, and the information is saved in a text file. The program has to know where to save that specific text file. I have added a menu button that directs you to an area of the program where you can tell the program where you would like the program to save the file. The problem is that I would like to have to tell the program where I would like to save the file once, and only once. So after I close the program I could open it back up, and it would remember where I would like to save the file.

This is not my exact code, just an example:

```
flub = raw_input("Where would you like to save your file?)
SaveDirectory = flub
```

In this case, `SaveDirectory` is where I want to save the file. I would like the program to ask me where I would like to save the program once, and only once.

Comment: You must save the `SaveDirectory` variable into a file and retrieve it once the program begins.

Comment: You can make a config file and use it to store permenent settings. See here a simple example [Quickly application create config folder and config file under user's home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335881/quickly-application-create-config-folder-and-config-file-under-users-home-folde) . Another sophisticated way is to store user preferences/settings using Gsettings API, See [What is the schema XML file in the data/glib-2.0 folder of my Quickly application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165890/what-is-the-schema-xml-file-in-the-data-glib-2-0-folder-of-my-quickly-applicatio)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How to have to change a variable once, and never change it again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482409/python-how-to-have-to-change-a-variable-once-and-never-change-it-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had answered this for you before, but if your still really stuck try something like this, you should be able to go from here (Note: in this example "datafile.txt" must exist first):

```
import os 
flub = raw_input('Where would you like your save directory to be?')

file = open("datafile.txt", "r")
filedata = file.read()
file.close()

try:
    if os.stat("datafile.txt").st_size > 0:
        print "Value exists already"
else:
    file = open("datafile.txt", "w")
    file.write(flub)
    file.close()
    print "flub value updated to: " + flub
except OSError:
    print "No file"
```

Comment: I got what you were trying to say, and I tweaked your program a lot, and found what I was looking for. Thank you!