# Python GTK: How to stop a function from happening if a checkbox is checked

Tags: python, gtk, glade

In my program I have one of those annoying popups that alerts the user to go check the settings. I have a checkbox that if checked, is supposed to never show the popup again. I have no idea how to do that. When the check box is checked I need the program to write to a text file called tog_file.txt saying "true". And if the text in tog_file.txt says true, the popup will never display again. Code:

```
def reminder():
    global tog
    tog = open("tog_file.txt", "r+b")
    tog_r = tog.read()
    if tog_r == "true":
        print "true"
    if tog_r == "":
        global reminder
        reminder = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        reminder.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        reminder.set_size_request(450, 205)
        reminder.set_title("Info")

        textbox = gtk.Label("Remember To Go Into The Settings Menu! There are Important Settings that Need to be Reviewed by you!")
        textbox.set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_CENTER) 
        textbox.set_line_wrap(True)   

        button = gtk.Button("Close")
        button.connect("clicked", reminder_close)

        toggle = gtk.CheckButton("Don't Show This Message Again")
        item_text = toggle.get_active()
        if item_text == False:
            print "no"
        if item_text == True:
            print "yea"
            tog.write("true")

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        fixed.put(button, 300, 160)
        fixed.put(toggle, 50, 165)
        fixed.put(textbox, 50, 50)

        reminder.add(fixed)
        reminder.show_all()

    def reminder_close(self):
        reminder.destroy()
```

If you need any additional information, just post a comment. Thanks StackOverflow :)

Comment: The answer I gave here should help you do what you need: http://askubuntu.com/questions/482419/python-how-can-i-store-a-variable-changed-by-the-user/482428?noredirect=1#comment642175_482428

Comment: Is there a reason you're using python GTK instead of pygi?  You also might want to add some context.  Is it a script you run once, so it needs to save a setting somewhere, does it run as a service, does it run as an app?  All two of the three have a different answer.